# TSQL Multiple insert on splitstring

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently using a tsql split strings function which is like so:

```
USE [local]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[splitstring]    Script Date: 11/22/2013    
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[splitstring] ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

RETURN
 END
```

This allows me to pass a string of data like so : dog,cat,mouse,pig

It produces the output below in a table.

[image]

From this point, i want to run an insert statement for each of the tags that are passed and in the table.

```
--INSERT  INTO Tags_Accounts (data, dataType, dataLocation, tag, whoAdded, whenAdded)
    --VALUES                         (@dbData, @dbDataType, @location, @tags, @ntid, GETDATE());
```

This is how i can access the table data but not sure how to run the insert for each time it exists.

SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring (@tags)

In this case, it would run 4 insert statements as there were 4 tags in the temp table.

How could I go about doing this ?

Comment: It would be better, if possible, to switch to using table-valued parameters - a data structure *built* for containing multiple values of the same "type" - unlike these CSV strings which are just a bodge.

Comment: Checkout this articel: [Using select to insert data](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-select-to-insert-records)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I'm sure there is a better way to do this that I'm not aware of. I just allow users to tag an article so there could be 10 tags. Now rather than do 10 db calls, i just want to pass the tags as a string and then for each of them, do an insert in the stored procedure. What would be an ideal solution for this ?

Comment: The ideal would be to populate a table-valued parameter with (up to) 10 *rows* of data and pass that to SQL. This could then be used naturally in an `INSERT...SELECT` statement.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I am a little confused on how that would look from the code side of things. Would my ajax call be inserting 1 record at a time into this temp table or is there a way to pass it all at once like I am doing on the split?

Comment: Well, I'm guessing that the AJAX isn't directly hitting SQL Server. If you've got, say, .NET code sitting in between, you can check the [ADO.NET Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx). In turn, though, the AJAX code could then be switched to passing an array rather than a CSV.

Comment: My ajax call passes the data to a stored procedure. The param I am sending with it is a string of tags comma separated. I could have it pass it as an array if the stored procedure can do something with an array paramater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all of your other variables (`@dbData`, `@dbDataType`, `@location`, `@ntid`) will be the same for each row returned by `[dbo].[splitstring]`, this should work:

```
INSERT INTO Tags_Accounts 
    (data, dataType, dataLocation, tag, whoAdded, whenAdded)
SELECT 
    @dbData, @dbDataType, @location, Name, @ntid, GETDATE() 
FROM dbo.splitstring (@tags);
```